# Feed DeepZoom control from database

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

Does anyone know an example of feeding DeepZoom control from the database, not from the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my initial thoughts on this were you'd probably need to write your own [MultiScaleTileSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.multiscaletilesource(VS.95).aspx) which returns tiles from a source other than the file system.

Quick Google on that subject has thrown up this article which looks to be exactly what you're after: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DatabaseDeepZoom.aspx